# special characters in django admin

Tags: django, unicode, ascii, admin, codec

Simple, really.
Using MySQL backend, I'm trying to save a model instance with the name "Protégé" from the Django admin.
But I get the dreaded unicode error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /admin/foo/bar/226/
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way to fix this without extending the admin?
Table is `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`.

Thanks!

P.S. Running the generated SQL directly works just fine

Comment: did you define a `__str__` or `__unicode__` in that model? did you overwrite `save()`?

Comment: Yes, I defined `__unicode__`.

Comment: Thanks, Private. That got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is often a probem in the definition in `__unicode__`. Make sure you define a `__unicode__` method in your model class and make sure it returns a unicode string.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll include an example for others:

Comment: `def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s-%s" % (unicode(self.foo), unicode(self.bar))`

Comment: I think you can also just do `return u"%s-%s" % self.foo, self.bar` where the `u` indicates that you are using a unicode string.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in some models - basically in all models where I forgot to override the unicode method correctly. In my case I was running the backend on a Windows machine first which works fine, but when I released the backend on a Linux machine I got the same error when editing a model. So here is how I fixed it. First of all the model class starts with `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` (on the first line!). Within the model I override `__unicode__` and return an unicode string.

This can be done by return `unicode(self.name)` or how I used it `u'%s' %(self.name)` or `u'Name: %s, Value: %s' %(self.name, self.value)`.

It's NOT working if you `return self.name` because that does not ensure to return unicoded strings.

Here's a full example:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import ... # all imports etc. after the coding: UTF-8 line!

class ModelName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %(self.name)
```

Hope it helps!

Best regards, Michael